# AMD 5600H drivers

Tags: power-management, 21.04, amd-ryzen

I am using 21.04 on a laptop with AMD Ryzen 5600H. Where can I get the drivers involved ? I ask because I am having trouble with power management. I tried using

https://github.com/AdnanHodzic/auto-cpufreq

But I get only 50% battery backup of what I get on dual boot Windows 10. I am trying to get out of this problem. Hopefully, proper drivers might fix it(?).

Comment: AMD CPU and graphics drivers are open-source and automatically installed.

Comment: Thanks. I was told that I get poor battery backup due to lack of proper drivers.

Comment: There's a complex dialectic of factors. A worse result in Ubuntu/Linux can be blamed on less developed/polished/optimized "drivers" but only partially. Most of the time the difference is noticeable because users aren't really comparing results under identical circumstances. Namely with hybrid graphics the "on demand" Windows optimizations make a very noticeable difference. And, of course, most of the times it boils down to a very different workload.